# "startproject" option disappeared from django-admin.py

Tags: django, django-admin

I apologize in advance for my noobness. I tried to create a new project with "django-admin.py startproject blah" and I got an error saying "startproject" is an unknown option for django-admin.py. This can't be normal. I then did "django-admin.py help" and viewed the possible arguments, and they were the same as the arguments for manage.py (startapp, sqlall, sqlflush). What on earth is going on?

Comment: What system? I had similar problem on windows xp, on linux none :)

Comment: @Rinz - I've used Django on Windows XP and never encountered this.

Comment: I"m on windows XP--haven't encountered this before (which is why it's weirding me out). I've been using the ORM to manage data projects for months without any problems until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already in a project, `startproject` is explicitly removed from `manage.py` and `django-admin.py`. From the docstring to django.core.management.get_commands:

> If a settings module has been
>   specified, user-defined commands will
>   also be included, the startproject
>   command will be disabled, and the
>   startapp command will be modified to
>   use the directory in which the
>   settings module appears.

Comment: This is correct. You need to back out of your existing project directory before you start a new one.

Comment: Thank's very much,you guys saved me.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Django Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname):

```
[startproject] is disabled [...] when the environment
variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE has been set. To
re-enable it in these situations, [...] unset
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
```

I ran across this just the other day and it caused me some amount of groaning when I finally figured it out.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly formatting. The underscores in DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE don't get rendered otherwise.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. Problem de-mystified! Next time I will RTFM.